# How to make building timer in spritekit game?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

There are two decisions to make timers, with "update:" and with actions.
But i need a timer that could continue even if the player close the game.
So when player comes back to game after a certain time, his progress could be saved. Could i use CFAbsoluteTime to make this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the Date/Time instead of in-app timers for this purpose.

Essentially, you need to track the time passed between launches of the app. You can do this via storing the Date in the user defaults when the app is closed, and comparing it to the current Date when the app is openened the next time to figure out how much time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using an external clock, like grabbing the time from a website,  this will prevent people from simply changing there clocks to alter time. (This will not however prevent people from altering the DNS to go to there own web servers, but will most people go through that trouble for a simple game)